# Set datefirst dynamically by the first day of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have fallen a problem to set date first into my SQL query. Here is the code below where I have set by using IF, Else IF. But I need one sql statement not IF, Else IF.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE, @FirstDayOfWeek INT
SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SELECT @FirstDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW,@CurrentDate)

IF @FirstDayOfWeek = 6
    SET DATEFIRST 5; --friday
ELSE IF @FirstDayOfWeek = 7
    SET DATEFIRST 6; --sunday
--AND SO ON
```

Comment: So just deduct 1 from the @FirstDayOfWeek? Why do you need "one SQL statement"?

Comment: I don't see how the first day of the year comes into play. It looks like you're setting the the first day of the week to be whatever the weekday is for the current date.  Will this only be called on the first day of the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `DATEPART(DW, . . .)` depends on the current value of `@@DATEFIRST`, so you need to take that into account when setting the new value of `@@DATEFIRST`.  The simplest thing would be to set `@@DATEFIRST` back to 1, get the current day of the week, and then set `@@DATEFIRST` to that.

By the way, if you just want the date of a date-time, you can just cast it to `DATE`.  Ultimately, though, there's no need to convert the date-time to a date, because the result of `DATEPART(DW, . . .)` will be the same either way.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE, @CurrentDayOfWeek INT
SET @CurrentDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- normalize first day of week
SET @CurrentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
SET DATEFIRST @CurrentDayOfWeek
```

Or

```
DECLARE @CurrentDayOfWeek INT
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- normalize first day of week
SET @CurrentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())
SET DATEFIRST @CurrentDayOfWeek
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDayOfWeek INT
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- normalize first day of week to Monday
SET @CurrentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, '2016-01-01') -- a Friday, which will be 5 because first day of week is currently 1
SET DATEFIRST @CurrentDayOfWeek -- first day of week is now 5 (Friday)
```

Comment: need result 5 for this year of 2016. not 7

Comment: My solution will result in 5 for 2016-01-01.  See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for helpful example

Comment: No problem, Shohel. If this solution worked for you, and is the best answer in your opinion, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question mentions `DATEFIRST`, but is there any reason you don't just calculate it based on how many days it has been since the first of the year?

```
SELECT ((DATEPART(DY, GETDATE()) - 1) % 7) + 1
```

---

*old answer:*

Just got to mention that if `DATEFIRST` has been changed from the default of 7, this will no longer work since `DATEPART(dw,...)` will return a different value.  The value used with `SET DATEFIRST` is *always* 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday, etc.  You can always to a `SET DATEFIRST 7` ahead of time...

Basically what you are doing is subtracting 1 and rolling back over to 7 if you hit 0.  You can just use the mod operator (`%`) for that:

Comment: hi, I want to set year wise first day of week not default

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME, @FirstDayOfWeek INT
SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SELECT @FirstDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW,@CurrentDate)

SELECT @FirstDayOfWeek = (SELECT CASE @FirstDayOfWeek
WHEN 6 THEN 5
WHEN 7 THEN 6
END )

SET DATEFIRST @FirstDayOfWeek
```